# Several methods on ActiveRecord Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

There are several methods I want to fire on an `after_update` callback

Is there a way to call them all without creating a new method just for them?

for example doing:

```
after_update [:method1, :method2]
```

instead of

```
after_update :do_all

def do_all
  method1
  method2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
after_update :method1, :method2
```

No need of array.